# Bouncy Castle signature verification fails for known good signature

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pkcs#7

I'm working with a platform that sends and receives very large AS/2 S/MIME messages and have problems verifying the signature for multipart/signed. The signatures that are generated by my code are valid and accepted by other systems. I can successfully verify my own signatures as well. Unfortunately my code chokes on some known good signatures from other systems, even for small messages. The verification code looks like this (simplified):

```java
CMSSignedDataParser sp = new CMSSignedDataParser(
  new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder()
    .setProvider("BC")
    .build(),
  new CMSTypedStream(contentStream),
  signature
);

sp.getSignedContent().drain();

// get signer cert from signer infos or pass it in as parameter
signer.verify(
  new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder()
    .setProvider("BC")
    .build(signerCert)
);
```

The verify method returns false for the "known good" signature. It does not throw, which it does if the digest is wrong. I have tried passing in the certificate as an argument and getting it from the signer infos. The code works for my own signatures. Changing to non-streaming classes with `CMSProcessableByteArray` makes no difference. Using `signerCert.getPublicKey()` also makes no difference.

Looking at the signature data, the "known good" to the right lacks an attribute table, otherwise the two are very similar.

```
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=inf  cons: SEQUENCE                               0:d=0  hl=2 l=inf  cons: SEQUENCE
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :pkcs7-signedD       2:d=1  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :pkcs7-signedD
   13:d=1  hl=2 l=inf  cons: cont [ 0 ]                            13:d=1  hl=2 l=inf  cons: cont [ 0 ]
   15:d=2  hl=2 l=inf  cons: SEQUENCE                              15:d=2  hl=2 l=inf  cons: SEQUENCE
   17:d=3  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :01                 17:d=3  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :01
   20:d=3  hl=2 l=  11 cons: SET                                   20:d=3  hl=2 l=  11 cons: SET
   22:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 cons: SEQUENCE                              22:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 cons: SEQUENCE
   24:d=5  hl=2 l=   5 prim: OBJECT            :sha1               24:d=5  hl=2 l=   5 prim: OBJECT            :sha1
   31:d=5  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL                                  31:d=5  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
   33:d=3  hl=2 l=inf  cons: SEQUENCE                              33:d=3  hl=2 l=inf  cons: SEQUENCE
   35:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :pkcs7-data         35:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :pkcs7-data
   46:d=4  hl=2 l=   0 prim: EOC                                   46:d=4  hl=2 l=   0 prim: EOC
   48:d=3  hl=2 l=inf  cons: cont [ 0 ]                       |    48:d=3  hl=4 l= 811 cons: cont [ 0 ]
   50:d=4  hl=4 l= 807 cons: SEQUENCE                         |    52:d=4  hl=4 l= 807 cons: SEQUENCE
   54:d=5  hl=4 l= 527 cons: SEQUENCE                         |    56:d=5  hl=4 l= 527 cons: SEQUENCE
   58:d=6  hl=2 l=   3 cons: cont [ 0 ]                       |    60:d=6  hl=2 l=   3 cons: cont [ 0 ]
   60:d=7  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :02            |    62:d=7  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :02
   63:d=6  hl=2 l=  16 prim: INTEGER           :153D15DC586C0 |    65:d=6  hl=2 l=  16 prim: INTEGER           :153D15DC586C0
   81:d=6  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE                         |    83:d=6  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE
   83:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha1WithRSAEn |    85:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha1WithRSAEn
   94:d=7  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL                             |    96:d=7  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
   96:d=6  hl=2 l=  25 cons: SEQUENCE                         |    98:d=6  hl=2 l=  25 cons: SEQUENCE
   98:d=7  hl=2 l=  23 cons: SET                              |   100:d=7  hl=2 l=  23 cons: SET
  100:d=8  hl=2 l=  21 cons: SEQUENCE                         |   102:d=8  hl=2 l=  21 cons: SEQUENCE
  102:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName    |   104:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName
  107:d=9  hl=2 l=  14 prim: UTF8STRING        :as2.example.s |   109:d=9  hl=2 l=  14 prim: UTF8STRING        :as2.example.s
  123:d=6  hl=2 l=  30 cons: SEQUENCE                         |   125:d=6  hl=2 l=  30 cons: SEQUENCE
  125:d=7  hl=2 l=  13 prim: UTCTIME           :190208065447Z |   127:d=7  hl=2 l=  13 prim: UTCTIME           :190208065447Z
  140:d=7  hl=2 l=  13 prim: UTCTIME           :240208070447Z |   142:d=7  hl=2 l=  13 prim: UTCTIME           :240208070447Z
  155:d=6  hl=2 l=  25 cons: SEQUENCE                         |   157:d=6  hl=2 l=  25 cons: SEQUENCE
  157:d=7  hl=2 l=  23 cons: SET                              |   159:d=7  hl=2 l=  23 cons: SET
  159:d=8  hl=2 l=  21 cons: SEQUENCE                         |   161:d=8  hl=2 l=  21 cons: SEQUENCE
  161:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName    |   163:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName
  166:d=9  hl=2 l=  14 prim: UTF8STRING        :as2.example.s |   168:d=9  hl=2 l=  14 prim: UTF8STRING        :as2.example.s
  182:d=6  hl=4 l= 290 cons: SEQUENCE                         |   184:d=6  hl=4 l= 290 cons: SEQUENCE
  186:d=7  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE                         |   188:d=7  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE
  188:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption |   190:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
  199:d=8  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL                             |   201:d=8  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
  201:d=7  hl=4 l= 271 prim: BIT STRING                       |   203:d=7  hl=4 l= 271 prim: BIT STRING
      0000 - 00 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01-01 00 cd f2 29 98 3b 8d          0000 - 00 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01-01 00 cd f2 29 98 3b 8d
      0010 - c5 14 d3 51 38 c8 bb ae-3b 19 9e 7a f9 8e 97 61          0010 - c5 14 d3 51 38 c8 bb ae-3b 19 9e 7a f9 8e 97 61
      0020 - 5e 99 3d cb cc 4f 4a a9-79 53 d5 ef 12 29 60 1e          0020 - 5e 99 3d cb cc 4f 4a a9-79 53 d5 ef 12 29 60 1e
      0030 - 8f 49 0a f3 dc 4c a0 39-71 ec 05 9c 27 44 ab b7          0030 - 8f 49 0a f3 dc 4c a0 39-71 ec 05 9c 27 44 ab b7
      0040 - 6d ee 5d ab 95 d7 d9 4c-9d 48 86 85 54 10 40 d1          0040 - 6d ee 5d ab 95 d7 d9 4c-9d 48 86 85 54 10 40 d1
      0050 - 7c b4 8a 6f 2c 5e 46 ab-89 9b d5 d7 27 dc 97 3e          0050 - 7c b4 8a 6f 2c 5e 46 ab-89 9b d5 d7 27 dc 97 3e
      0060 - ab d8 ff 71 36 59 96 89-5a 96 63 80 7f d5 77 89          0060 - ab d8 ff 71 36 59 96 89-5a 96 63 80 7f d5 77 89
      0070 - 24 07 f2 cc 88 a2 ae 2f-d8 97 91 6a ef a9 92 72          0070 - 24 07 f2 cc 88 a2 ae 2f-d8 97 91 6a ef a9 92 72
      0080 - 95 e3 c3 de 56 48 10 bb-be 2d bf 68 fe 51 69 72          0080 - 95 e3 c3 de 56 48 10 bb-be 2d bf 68 fe 51 69 72
      0090 - 64 cd 69 90 44 ff da 5e-fc c2 69 f6 71 36 73 09          0090 - 64 cd 69 90 44 ff da 5e-fc c2 69 f6 71 36 73 09
      00a0 - 31 58 1b 21 e3 19 2e 6b-ec a4 3f b9 ba 4e aa ae          00a0 - 31 58 1b 21 e3 19 2e 6b-ec a4 3f b9 ba 4e aa ae
      00b0 - 8b 46 22 9f fa 8b 6d 45-4e 0e e9 40 2e 27 08 5d          00b0 - 8b 46 22 9f fa 8b 6d 45-4e 0e e9 40 2e 27 08 5d
      00c0 - 7d 59 cf 81 ef c8 cf 9d-fb 35 9a f2 4f 62 01 80          00c0 - 7d 59 cf 81 ef c8 cf 9d-fb 35 9a f2 4f 62 01 80
      00d0 - 2d 9b 0e e3 09 f5 f2 75-63 3d 72 c8 2b 02 07 da          00d0 - 2d 9b 0e e3 09 f5 f2 75-63 3d 72 c8 2b 02 07 da
      00e0 - 0b ec e1 fd de 8f e4 0d-b9 e5 c3 62 3b 60 2d 8a          00e0 - 0b ec e1 fd de 8f e4 0d-b9 e5 c3 62 3b 60 2d 8a
      00f0 - 25 13 7e 87 6c df 63 9e-38 d7 84 e3 04 dd 07 31          00f0 - 25 13 7e 87 6c df 63 9e-38 d7 84 e3 04 dd 07 31
      0100 - 41 04 99 1a 67 45 29 c1-34 ed 02 03 01 00 01             0100 - 41 04 99 1a 67 45 29 c1-34 ed 02 03 01 00 01
  476:d=6  hl=2 l= 107 cons: cont [ 3 ]                       |   478:d=6  hl=2 l= 107 cons: cont [ 3 ]
  478:d=7  hl=2 l= 105 cons: SEQUENCE                         |   480:d=7  hl=2 l= 105 cons: SEQUENCE
  480:d=8  hl=2 l=  14 cons: SEQUENCE                         |   482:d=8  hl=2 l=  14 cons: SEQUENCE
  482:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Key Us |   484:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Key Us
  487:d=9  hl=2 l=   1 prim: BOOLEAN           :255           |   489:d=9  hl=2 l=   1 prim: BOOLEAN           :255
  490:d=9  hl=2 l=   4 prim: OCTET STRING                     |   492:d=9  hl=2 l=   4 prim: OCTET STRING
      0000 - 03 02 04 b0                                              0000 - 03 02 04 b0
  496:d=8  hl=2 l=  29 cons: SEQUENCE                         |   498:d=8  hl=2 l=  29 cons: SEQUENCE
  498:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Extend |   500:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Extend
  503:d=9  hl=2 l=  22 prim: OCTET STRING                     |   505:d=9  hl=2 l=  22 prim: OCTET STRING
      0000 - 30 14 06 08 2b 06 01 05-05 07 03 02 06 08 2b 06          0000 - 30 14 06 08 2b 06 01 05-05 07 03 02 06 08 2b 06
      0010 - 01 05 05 07 03 01                                        0010 - 01 05 05 07 03 01
  527:d=8  hl=2 l=  25 cons: SEQUENCE                         |   529:d=8  hl=2 l=  25 cons: SEQUENCE
  529:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Subjec |   531:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Subjec
  534:d=9  hl=2 l=  18 prim: OCTET STRING                     |   536:d=9  hl=2 l=  18 prim: OCTET STRING
      0000 - 30 10 82 0e 61 73 32 2e-76 61 6c 69 64 6f 6f 2e          0000 - 30 10 82 0e 61 73 32 2e-76 61 6c 69 64 6f 6f 2e
      0010 - 73 65                                                    0010 - 73 65
  554:d=8  hl=2 l=  29 cons: SEQUENCE                         |   556:d=8  hl=2 l=  29 cons: SEQUENCE
  556:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Subjec |   558:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Subjec
  561:d=9  hl=2 l=  22 prim: OCTET STRING                     |   563:d=9  hl=2 l=  22 prim: OCTET STRING
      0000 - 04 14 32 53 96 ec 74 b8-f0 17 9d e5 e7 7c 2f 2b          0000 - 04 14 32 53 96 ec 74 b8-f0 17 9d e5 e7 7c 2f 2b
      0010 - 9b 0e db ae 08 78                                        0010 - 9b 0e db ae 08 78
  585:d=5  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE                         |   587:d=5  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE
  587:d=6  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha1WithRSAEn |   589:d=6  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha1WithRSAEn
  598:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL                             |   600:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
  600:d=5  hl=4 l= 257 prim: BIT STRING                       |   602:d=5  hl=4 l= 257 prim: BIT STRING
      0000 - 00 32 90 8e 5e 2a a1 63-27 66 06 a9 2b c3 cf 1e          0000 - 00 32 90 8e 5e 2a a1 63-27 66 06 a9 2b c3 cf 1e
      0010 - 40 70 72 db b0 57 b0 b3-7e 0e 82 f3 40 8d e9 b5          0010 - 40 70 72 db b0 57 b0 b3-7e 0e 82 f3 40 8d e9 b5
      0020 - 41 fa 16 b2 d0 cf 95 bb-2b 50 d6 3c 2c bc 6f 81          0020 - 41 fa 16 b2 d0 cf 95 bb-2b 50 d6 3c 2c bc 6f 81
      0030 - e5 b3 2e 78 7c f9 44 e0-eb 88 79 0f 96 fa 84 e3          0030 - e5 b3 2e 78 7c f9 44 e0-eb 88 79 0f 96 fa 84 e3
      0040 - 99 fc f8 25 2f 46 1b 3a-45 b0 43 e7 e0 2c 81 f3          0040 - 99 fc f8 25 2f 46 1b 3a-45 b0 43 e7 e0 2c 81 f3
      0050 - f0 1a c4 b6 2e 0b a5 78-63 d2 79 15 04 25 64 58          0050 - f0 1a c4 b6 2e 0b a5 78-63 d2 79 15 04 25 64 58
      0060 - 06 29 05 20 38 68 1b 6e-3b ee 9b f3 51 67 52 73          0060 - 06 29 05 20 38 68 1b 6e-3b ee 9b f3 51 67 52 73
      0070 - 5f 10 22 0d 94 33 7a c3-61 a2 5a a3 85 cd c1 cb          0070 - 5f 10 22 0d 94 33 7a c3-61 a2 5a a3 85 cd c1 cb
      0080 - 77 19 30 43 86 46 2e 11-ac be 67 16 db fb 77 87          0080 - 77 19 30 43 86 46 2e 11-ac be 67 16 db fb 77 87
      0090 - b7 6a fc e2 16 55 42 ea-a7 4b 49 f2 45 50 5b aa          0090 - b7 6a fc e2 16 55 42 ea-a7 4b 49 f2 45 50 5b aa
      00a0 - d7 78 9d 3d c8 51 91 05-fb ee a3 7b 27 c7 71 25          00a0 - d7 78 9d 3d c8 51 91 05-fb ee a3 7b 27 c7 71 25
      00b0 - e9 34 e0 41 aa 35 cc a1-a3 ea 16 e7 25 f7 c3 34          00b0 - e9 34 e0 41 aa 35 cc a1-a3 ea 16 e7 25 f7 c3 34
      00c0 - 13 b6 25 e6 01 85 a8 41-74 ee ae 40 43 b7 1e ae          00c0 - 13 b6 25 e6 01 85 a8 41-74 ee ae 40 43 b7 1e ae
      00d0 - bf df 96 04 b4 27 f6 11-c5 8f a4 02 88 fa 66 d6          00d0 - bf df 96 04 b4 27 f6 11-c5 8f a4 02 88 fa 66 d6
      00e0 - 6d c5 bb 97 be f0 5f 3d-e3 db 7c 72 b3 76 63 7b          00e0 - 6d c5 bb 97 be f0 5f 3d-e3 db 7c 72 b3 76 63 7b
      00f0 - 12 34 ab c5 75 78 8c ab-00 9f 2a 10 60 5a 56 3f          00f0 - 12 34 ab c5 75 78 8c ab-00 9f 2a 10 60 5a 56 3f
      0100 - 47                                                       0100 - 47
  861:d=4  hl=2 l=   0 prim: EOC                              |   863:d=3  hl=4 l= 340 cons: SET
  863:d=3  hl=4 l= 597 cons: SET                              |   867:d=4  hl=4 l= 336 cons: SEQUENCE
  867:d=4  hl=4 l= 593 cons: SEQUENCE                         <
  871:d=5  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :01                871:d=5  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :01
  874:d=5  hl=2 l=  45 cons: SEQUENCE                             874:d=5  hl=2 l=  45 cons: SEQUENCE
  876:d=6  hl=2 l=  25 cons: SEQUENCE                             876:d=6  hl=2 l=  25 cons: SEQUENCE
  878:d=7  hl=2 l=  23 cons: SET                                  878:d=7  hl=2 l=  23 cons: SET
  880:d=8  hl=2 l=  21 cons: SEQUENCE                             880:d=8  hl=2 l=  21 cons: SEQUENCE
  882:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName        882:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName
  887:d=9  hl=2 l=  14 prim: UTF8STRING        :as2.example.s     887:d=9  hl=2 l=  14 prim: UTF8STRING        :as2.example.s
  903:d=6  hl=2 l=  16 prim: INTEGER           :153D15DC586C0     903:d=6  hl=2 l=  16 prim: INTEGER           :153D15DC586C0
  921:d=5  hl=2 l=   9 cons: SEQUENCE                             921:d=5  hl=2 l=   9 cons: SEQUENCE
  923:d=6  hl=2 l=   5 prim: OBJECT            :sha1              923:d=6  hl=2 l=   5 prim: OBJECT            :sha1
  930:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL                                 930:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
  932:d=5  hl=3 l= 254 cons: cont [ 0 ]                       |   932:d=5  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE
  935:d=6  hl=2 l=  24 cons: SEQUENCE                         |   934:d=6  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
  937:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :contentType   |   945:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
  948:d=7  hl=2 l=  11 cons: SET                              |   947:d=5  hl=4 l= 256 prim: OCTET STRING
  950:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :pkcs7-data    |       0000 - 6f 58 e3 71 97 28 86 cd-02 2e 7b e9 df c7 0c 8d
  961:d=6  hl=2 l=  28 cons: SEQUENCE                         |       0010 - 85 68 7f e7 ea 88 9f bd-76 d4 6f 7c e8 93 41 cf
  963:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :signingTime   |       0020 - ce 5b b7 c4 63 9a 75 48-88 1e e2 29 25 92 fc 92
  974:d=7  hl=2 l=  15 cons: SET                              |       0030 - 9a 86 8c 7f 08 5c 30 fd-ea fd 43 83 b9 4b a4 9d
  976:d=8  hl=2 l=  13 prim: UTCTIME           :220425160449Z |       0040 - 37 b4 d0 58 c5 6b e9 07-d3 21 62 30 63 16 a4 f4
  991:d=6  hl=2 l=  35 cons: SEQUENCE                         |       0050 - b1 ad 3c 1d 4f 1c a8 b8-7a 6d 65 4d 50 7e 65 58
  993:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :messageDigest |       0060 - 48 a0 5a aa 5b f4 db 3b-a8 ca a2 7a 50 41 75 d9
 1004:d=7  hl=2 l=  22 cons: SET                              |       0070 - 01 20 78 bc 0e 1b 58 82-b7 ec b9 22 3e fe 8d 44
 1006:d=8  hl=2 l=  20 prim: OCTET STRING                     |       0080 - 3c d3 26 76 69 54 17 e0-68 01 f7 82 73 cd 66 ab
      0000 - ba 30 61 18 8d e9 00 6b-46 9f 0e 00 b5 d8 36 f7  |       0090 - 3e 90 30 48 e8 84 5a 79-a1 aa 0d 74 46 ab 72 04
      0010 - 33 1d 9d 77                                      |       00a0 - 18 0f c7 c0 bc db c0 12-a3 34 82 31 f5 92 28 87
 1028:d=6  hl=2 l=  41 cons: SEQUENCE                         |       00b0 - b4 44 0e 4e 26 9a 19 a8-96 01 98 59 69 3c 80 e3
 1030:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :1.2.840.11354 |       00c0 - 8c a5 5c b8 33 dc 14 16-d7 28 72 97 6e 93 fe 9c
 1041:d=7  hl=2 l=  28 cons: SET                              |       00d0 - 04 cf 0e 50 b8 1f 1c b7-7b cf da 79 12 ac 09 2a
 1043:d=8  hl=2 l=  26 cons: SEQUENCE                         |       00e0 - c4 7d 04 e8 93 12 8c c4-dc 85 af ce fc 00 75 97
 1045:d=9  hl=2 l=   9 cons: SEQUENCE                         |       00f0 - fc 01 47 5a 59 99 a9 5d-c2 dc ce ae 9e 53 42 15
 1047:d=10 hl=2 l=   5 prim: OBJECT            :sha1          |  1207:d=3  hl=2 l=   0 prim: EOC
 1054:d=10 hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL                             |  1209:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: EOC
 1056:d=9  hl=2 l=  13 cons: cont [ 1 ]                       |  1211:d=1  hl=2 l=   0 prim: EOC
 1058:d=10 hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption <
 1069:d=10 hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL                             <
 1071:d=6  hl=2 l=  52 cons: SEQUENCE                         <
 1073:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :S/MIME Capabi <
 1084:d=7  hl=2 l=  39 cons: SET                              <
 1086:d=8  hl=2 l=  37 cons: SEQUENCE                         <
 1088:d=9  hl=2 l=  10 cons: SEQUENCE                         <
 1090:d=10 hl=2 l=   8 prim: OBJECT            :des-ede3-cbc  <
 1100:d=9  hl=2 l=  14 cons: SEQUENCE                         <
 1102:d=10 hl=2 l=   8 prim: OBJECT            :rc2-cbc       <
 1112:d=10 hl=2 l=   2 prim: INTEGER           :80            <
 1116:d=9  hl=2 l=   7 cons: SEQUENCE                         <
 1118:d=10 hl=2 l=   5 prim: OBJECT            :des-cbc       <
 1125:d=6  hl=2 l=  62 cons: SEQUENCE                         <
 1127:d=7  hl=2 l=  11 prim: OBJECT            :id-smime-aa-e <
 1140:d=7  hl=2 l=  47 cons: SET                              <
 1142:d=8  hl=2 l=  45 cons: cont [ 0 ]                       <
 1144:d=9  hl=2 l=  25 cons: SEQUENCE                         <
 1146:d=10 hl=2 l=  23 cons: SET                              <
 1148:d=11 hl=2 l=  21 cons: SEQUENCE                         <
 1150:d=12 hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName    <
 1155:d=12 hl=2 l=  14 prim: UTF8STRING        :as2.example.s <
 1171:d=9  hl=2 l=  16 prim: INTEGER           :153D15DC586C0 <
 1189:d=5  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE                         <
 1191:d=6  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption <
 1202:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL                             <
 1204:d=5  hl=4 l= 256 prim: OCTET STRING                     <
      0000 - bd 8b 48 4d 61 ce 09 9c-d9 89 b8 52 15 55 9f 87  <
      0010 - 8f 9b 45 23 00 77 a0 5b-c0 50 72 fe 78 4e f6 25  <
      0020 - ed 6d 02 82 77 6b 9c 84-f0 04 82 c5 30 3a 50 21  <
      0030 - 0a 51 40 01 fa 65 74 fd-0c 99 4b c7 e8 31 b1 09  <
      0040 - 6d bd e5 c2 72 19 8c 14-07 3b 9c 00 ca cd ee ef  <
      0050 - 87 db c6 fa 0f e9 41 9d-28 fa ac 95 46 b7 6d e3  <
      0060 - 83 9e 16 bf b2 14 90 54-b4 d8 09 67 e1 11 c6 e2  <
      0070 - b9 3c d6 54 06 08 16 87-2b 0f 21 a3 66 14 a1 fc  <
      0080 - 1b a7 93 19 84 ad 89 8f-a7 7f 53 5c 2f 44 ae 94  <
      0090 - 00 ce 01 e6 16 3c 19 89-0b b7 30 a3 b4 c4 94 ae  <
      00a0 - 71 4e 7d 3d 7b ad 3d e0-d2 f0 36 d7 b9 4f 47 08  <
      00b0 - 13 6f ad 2e 54 db 33 be-c0 63 db 5d 1b d6 a5 71  <
      00c0 - 01 7a 63 32 9e f5 3e 36-53 8e 12 14 b2 53 ef fb  <
      00d0 - 3f cb 07 85 9e 98 09 f0-75 43 22 23 21 74 c8 5d  <
      00e0 - 72 bd 43 ae 76 82 43 bc-48 bd 07 08 c6 5f 3d 75  <
      00f0 - cc 7b 4d 81 31 67 1c d2-b7 f0 84 da 62 86 14 a1  <
 1464:d=3  hl=2 l=   0 prim: EOC                              <
 1466:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: EOC                              <
 1468:d=1  hl=2 l=   0 prim: EOC                              <
```

What could be wrong and how can I configure the BouncyCastle code to make this validation pass? The content digests are correct and other systems accept the signature, so there must be something I have missed. Unfortunately I have checked several samples without finding any clues. I can't rewrite everything to use the BouncyCastle S/MIME classes, especially as I don't even know if it would help.

Comment: An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be by far your best chance to get a helpful reply. While the semi hex-dump you provided might help a mega expert to answer your question, I am afraid you might not be so lucky. So if you can make the problem reproducible - maybe using test certificates you can share with the public - please do so. I am finding it rather difficult to debug a tiny code snippet with some log output I cannot even use as a certificate without reverse-engineering it back into its binary form.

Comment: I'll try to arrange one. The code is no problem, getting the remote end to sign using a test certificate is harder.

Comment: For SignerInfo with signedattrs, `.verify` throws if hash of the data doesn't match the attrib and returns false if the signature doesn't verify for hash _of the signedattrs_, while without signedattrs (your right-hand case) it returns false if the signature doesn't verify for hash _of the data_. In that case lack of throw does not prove the data/hash is correct, and I suspect it's not -- but we need an example to check. Note we need the _exact_ data, even things like linebreaks matter, so don't just cut&paste, use hex or base64 or else something like pastebin. ...

Comment: ... @ewramner: actually you don't need the cert, the publickey (with alg = SPKI) which you can recover here is enough to test, but per above you do need the _exact_ data which we don't have.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 if you make an answer of that I'll accept it. It was a data error (non-canonical headers), but I didn't know how the exception logic worked and assumed the data was correct as there was no exception. Your comment put me on the right track.